# Ordering VARCHARs that contain numbers

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, natural-sort

I have a list of locations within a room stored in a table. They are mostly named A1, A2, ... A16, B1, B2, ... B16, C1...

When querying against this list, how would I sort the results so that the letters are grouped with the numbers in order?

Obviously `SELECT name FROM Shelves ORDER BY name` doesn't work, as it returns A1, A10, ... A16, A2.

`FROM Location ORDER BY LENGTH(name)` doesn't work either, as the A's, B's, C's, etc are no longer grouped.

EDIT:

Not all location names are a single character followed by numbers, there is also Safe 1, Safe 2, Safe 3, Currency 1, Currency 2... (shelves within safes in the room).

A1 and such do not have a space, but Safe 1, Currency 1 and such do.

Comment: Search for `[postgresql] [natural-sort]` and you'll find other duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex to separate names from numbers

```
SELECT *
FROM Shelves  
ORDER BY
regexp_replace(name , '[^a-zA-Z]*', '', 'g') ,
regexp_replace(name , '[^0-9]*', '', 'g')::INT
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...
SELECT name FROM Shelves ORDER BY name ASC